# Contribution Page Time to Submit

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor, stripe

Our contribution pages are not as fast as I would expect. What is the expected time people see to submit a CiviContribute page out of the box? Up until recently, it was reliably within 20-25s using Stripe which was at the outer limits of my expectations but serviceable.

Now contributions take from 30-35s. The increase seems to have occurred within the last month.

The factors I can see that are affecting submissions are:

- USPS standardization
- Google geocoding
- Deduping to a large database
- Stripe
- Cividesk Normalize

We also experience a cookies error intermittently after submitting a donation.

[image]

In other words, the donor does not get to the thank you page but gets the following error. The donation does succeed. This issue has persisted for a long-time. We have not seen any pattern for when it occurs. I would estimate that it occurs 10-20% of the time.

This is related: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/517 and says using PHP 7.2 resolved, but we are already on 7.2.

## Testing

- CiviCRM 5.28.3
- Processors: Stripe 6.4.2 / PayPal Standard / Authorize.net
- Browser: Chrome

Baseline time to submission: Using Stripe with USPS standardization, CiviDesk Normalize, Geocoding: 32 seconds.

Test 1 - Stripe: Disable Cividesk Normalize and USPS standardization: 35s

Test 2 - Stripe: Above and disabled Google Geocoding + Geofill: 29s

Test 3 - Authorize.net and enabled above extensions: 23s

Test 4 - Authorize.net and disabled above extensions: 23s

Test 5 - PayPal Standard and enabled above extensions: 17s

Test 6 - PayPal Standard and disabled above extensions: 17s

So it appears to be related to Stripe.

For reference civicrm.org runs Stripe and donating there it took 7s to confirmation page and 9s to submit.

**Update: The common factors of the slowness is WP + large database + Stripe.**

Ref: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/-/issues/246

Answer (score 2):

17 seconds from pressing "Submit" to the thank-you page is still obscenely high.  My only client who comes close to this has maybe 80 extensions installed.  My guess is you have something going on already that's exacerbated by Stripe.

While it's not the easiest solution, doing an [xdebug profiling session](https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) would be really helpful here.  E.g. I once found a bug in the token processor that made contact creation take a long time - and when I added an extension with custom tokens, the problem got even worse.  Something comparable may be happening here.

Comment: I tested my client with 80+ extensions with Stripe 6.5 and they returned in 11 seconds, FWIW.

Comment: The commonality thus far is large db size + Wordpress + Stripe. What CMS are they on?

Comment: Drupal 8, about a quarter million contacts.  Also using Redis, which is a good idea if you have a large db